# How to use EnvironmentObject to initialize State Property in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, initialization, state, environment

I am having a small Issue with initializing a `State` with Data from an `EnvironmentObject`.

```swift
@EnvironmentObject var settings: Settings
    
@State var localAllowReminders: Bool
    
init() {
    self._localAllowReminders = State(initialValue: settings.allowReminders)
}
```

> Obviously, I get the following Error Message: **'self' used before all stored properties are initialized.**

**Question:** How can I initialize a State with Data out of a EnvironmentObject?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're best off not using `@EnvironmentObject` but rather injecting `Settings` properly and storing it as `@ObservedObject`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`EnvironmentObject` is injected **after** view constructor call, so you have to initialize state to some default and reset it to desired value in top body view `onAppear` modifier, like

```
@EnvironmentObject var settings: Settings
@State var localAllowReminders: Bool = false   // << just any default
    
var body: some View {
    VStack {       // << any top view
        // ...
    }
    .onAppear {
       self.localAllowReminders = settings.allowReminders   // << here !!
    }
}
```

Comment: May I know how do you know that EnvironmentObject is injected after view constructor call?

Comment: @onthemoon, I am getting error `No ObservableObject of type "" found` when I am trying to get access to environment object from `.onAppear` method